# How to inherit jQuery UI's widget's options from archive

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, user-interface, configuration

I'm just trying do write some JavaScript code to set some options for a jQuery UI's widget in an external configuration file that looks like the following lines:

```
$(function($){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != 1)];
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that when I write some code in another page to add some options for a sepecific page, the options in my external file are not overwritten. For example: the lines above is what I have in my configuration file and the lines **below** is what I'm writing in the HTML pages that I use the component:

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date) {
            var diaDaSemana = new Date(date);
            var arrayHorarios = new Array();
            diaDaSemana.getDay() == 0 ? preencherHorarios(arrayHorariosDomingo) : preencherHorarios(arrayHorariosNormais);
        }
    });
```

It overwrites the options in my configuration files, and what I wanna know is: **How to inherit that options without overwriting then even if I don't set the properties that I wan't to overwrite**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set options for an already initialised datepicker:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1)];
    }
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker("option", "onSelect", function(date) {
    var diaDaSemana = new Date(date);
    var arrayHorarios = new Array();
    diaDaSemana.getDay() == 0 ? preencherHorarios(arrayHorariosDomingo) : preencherHorarios(arrayHorariosNormais);
});
```